# Django dev server does not start if noreload is not set

Tags: python, django, django-extensions

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to start the Django development server with `runserver_plus` from [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/tree/main)

When I initiate it with the following command:

```py
python backoffice/manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000 --noreload
```

It starts successfully without any problems. However, if I use the following command instead

```py
python backoffice/manage.py runserver_plus 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Notice that if I not pass the `--noreload` flag, it returns the following error:

```
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:8000
 * Running on http://192.168.0.16:8000
Press CTRL+C to quit
 * Restarting with stat
/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file '/Users/user/dev/backoffice/manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The command is being executed in the same place so it does not make sense why is not finding the manage file.

Why does it only work when I include --noreload? Is there a way to make it work? I would like to use the reload capability to save time in development process.

Versions:

```
python 3.11
Django 4.1.9
django-extensions 3.2.1
```

Thank you!

Comment: Consider providing the versions you are using of python and django and any relevant logs that (in development environment) will be logged directly to the terminal.

Comment: @Dimitar thank you, I added versions and more info on the console response